# Im trying to add data into my users table in the database

Tags: php, database, postgresql

I have tried various solutions but the data is not being added into the users table in the database. Its always going to home.php. Please help. Thank you

```
<?php
$host="localhost";
$user="postgres";
$pass="password";
$db ="sportclub";
$con=pg_connect("host=$host dbname=$db user=$user password=$pass") or die ("Could not connect to Server\n");
    
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $uname=$_POST['name'];
    $uemail=$_POST['email'];
    $upass=$_POST['pass'];
    $contact=$_POST['contact'];
    $regdate=$_POST['regdate'];
    $uadd=$_POST['address'];

$sql="INSERT INTO users (USER_NAME,USER_EMAIL,USER_PASSWORD,USER_CONTACT,USER_ADDRESS,REGISTER_DATE) VALUES ('$uname','$uemail','$upass','$contact','$regdate','$uadd')";
$result=pg_query($con,$sql);
if ($result){
    header("Location:login.php");
    }
else{
    header('Location:home.php');
    }
}
pg_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: Check your Insert statement, it looks like you reversed the column name and parameter values for user_address and register_date. Statement has insert( ..., user_address,register_date) while the values clause has *values(... '$regdate','$uadd'). Order of columns in insert is positional and values must match.

Answer (score 1):

1. Check the output of [pg_last_error()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pg-last-error.php). That may point you in the right direction.
2. Also, you should hash user passwords before storing them in a database and then compare the hashes when they try and login.
3. Read about SQL Injections. You cannot directly pass user inputs to db.

Comment: Am answer does not need to prove a full set of working code. Specific pieces of advice can be just as useful (and I'm many cases, more) then answers that are just code.